# How to create a JSON string with key/value pairs from web.config appsettings?

Tags: c#, json.net

I need to loop through the app settings collection of web.config and add the key value pairs in a JSON string. I am using JSON.Net. How can I prepare a JSON string inside the for loop? Thank you!

```
foreach (string key in ConfigurationManager.AppSettings)
{
    string value = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[key];
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since [AppSettings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.appsettings%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is a [NameValueCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.namevaluecollection(v=vs.110).aspx), you cannot convert it directly to Json. You should populate a [Dictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) from it and serialize it using the [JsonConvert](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_SerializeObject_1.htm) class:

```
Dictionary<string, string> items = new Dictionary<string, string>();
foreach (string key in ConfigurationManager.AppSettings) {
    string value = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[key];
    items.Add(key, value);
}
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(items, Formatting.Indented);
```

Answer (score 3):

Extending [Mehrzad Chehraz's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30268054/4905310), for those who don't need to iterate through the AppSettings keys:

```
public string GetJsonNetSerializedString()
{
    var keys = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.AllKeys
        .Select(key => new 
        { 
            Key = key, 
            Value = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[key] 
        });
    string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(keys, Formatting.Indented);
    return json;
}
```